# laravel mysql -problem with data extraction

Tags: laravel

hello I learn laravel I have a problem I have a mysql database with a table breakdowns in it columns machine_name and data_zgnoszeniaawarii, I need help because I do not know how to extract data from the database in the form
machine name and number of occurrences, how to pass it to blade.php, e.g.
machine name
machine - NR01
number of appearances
5
is it something like this:

```
$quantity_of_of_machine =DB::select( DB::raw("SELECT numer_maszyny, COUNT(*) FROM `awaries` GROUP BY numer_maszyny") );
```

or

```
$quantity_of_of_machine = DB::table('awaries')
->select('numer_maszyny')
->groupBy('numer_maszyny')
->where('data_zgloszenia', '!=', null)
->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
->count();
```

Comment: could you please add the table scheme, and the Model name

Answer (score 1):

It is better if you add the table scheme, but now I can say you should do something like this:

```
DB::table('awaries')->selectRaw('numer_maszyny, count(*)')
    ->groupBy('numer_maszyny')
    ->where('data_zgloszenia', '!=', null)
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id); // ->get();
```

Comment: works great result is [{"machine_number": "AUTOMAT-09", "count (*)": 1}, {"machine_number": "AUTOMAT-18", "count (*)": 1}], now it remains to add this to the <li> in blade.php, however, I fail

Comment: @HubertGościniak You could use `foreach` in laravel blade. see here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#loops

Comment: @HubertGościniak Please accept this answer as solution  if it is helpful.